# Is there a way to see if two "references" reference the same place in Google Places API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

From [Google Places documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search)

> reference contains a unique token that you can use to retrieve additional information about this place in a Place Details request. You can store this token and use it at any time in future to refresh cached data about this Place, but the same token is not guaranteed to be returned for any given Place across different searches.

You can use a reference to retrieve information about a place, but if you get that place in a search in the future, it won't have the same reference. Multiple references will reference the same place. Is there a way to test if two references that I stored are for the same place? When I store references, it's creating redundancy in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that the only distinct feature of a place is the google+ -`url` returned by a [details-request](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsResults)

Answer (score 0):

Check the `id` value, which will always be the same for one place.